# Python modules are not seen in PHP

Tags: php, python

I'm trying to call a Python script from PHP using shell_exec(). However, what works in my Windows terminal doesn't work when I call it through PHP.

My call.php:

```
echo shell_exec("python C:\Desktop\a.py");
```

My a.py:

```
import cv2
print("Hello")
```

In this example I see Hello when I run through CMD but don't get the same response when I call it through PHP. Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. When using Windows for PHP "\" backslashes accepted as escape. So, to overcome this use "/" for your path.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
exec('python C:\Desktop\a.py');
```

The `shell_exec()` function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to execute the commands via shell and return the complete output as a string. The `shell_exec` is an alias for the backtick operator, for those used to `*nix`. If the command fails to return NULL and the values are not reliable for error checking.

The `exec()` function is an inbuilt function in PHP which is used to execute an external program and returns the last line of the output. It also returns NULL if no command runs properly.

I just thought `shell_exec` is not able to run so suggested other command.
I have tested both of the commands are working fine. Just the issue can be off path or rights of the file.

Comment: Can you explain why/how using the [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function will solve the issue? I'm not saying it won't, but a fully formed answer needs a little explanation, not just code. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hey @Raja, thanks for the message but that didn't worked out.

Comment: @tshimkus updated, sorry i am new don't know much about stackoverflow